# How to get offset from timestamp in JAVA

Tags: java, timezone, dst

I have two timestamps `1498329000000` and `1485282600000` in `Europe/Brussels`-

In which first one exist in Day Light saving and second one is non day light saving

How to get offset in positive or negative (difference) from `UTC`? i.e either 1hr or 2 hr , based on `DST`.

Comment: What you are asking for has multiple implementation based on opinions. You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a better question .

Comment: What did your search and research bring up? How was it insufficient? What have you tried? In what way did it fail? We can guide you much better when you provide such information in your question. Best from the outset, of course,

Comment: Note that timestamps like those are *always* in UTC.  They are not *in* `Europe/Brussels`.  You just seem to want the offset for `Europe/Brussels` at those particular UTC-based timestamps.

Answer (score 2):

With the `java.time`-API it's quite easy:

```
public static ZoneOffset getZoneOffset(long epochMillis, String zoneName) {
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMillis);
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of(zoneName));
    return zonedDateTime.getOffset();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getZoneOffset(1498329000000l, "Europe/Brussels")); // +02:00
    System.out.println(getZoneOffset(1485282600000l, "Europe/Brussels")); // +01:00
}
```

---

Also have a look at the class [`ZoneRules`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html) which have sone helpful methods for working with timezones and Daylight Savings Time (DST):

- [`boolean isDaylightSavings(Instant instant)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#isDaylightSavings-java.time.Instant-)

  > Checks if the specified instant is in daylight savings.
  >
  > This checks if the standard offset and the actual offset are the same for the specified instant. If they are not, it is assumed that daylight savings is in operation.
  >
  > This default implementation compares the actual and standard offsets.
  >
  > **Parameters:**
  >   `instant` - the instant to find the offset information for, not null, but null may be ignored if the rules have a single offset for all instants
  >
  > **Returns:**
  >   the standard offset, not null
- [`Duration getDaylightSavings(Instant instant)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#getDaylightSavings-java.time.Instant-)

  > Gets the amount of daylight savings in use for the specified instant in this zone.
  >
  > This provides access to historic information on how the amount of daylight savings has changed over time. This is the difference between the standard offset and the actual offset. Typically the amount is zero during winter and one hour during summer. Time-zones are second-based, so the nanosecond part of the duration will be zero.
  >
  > This default implementation calculates the duration from the actual and standard offsets.
  >
  > **Parameters:**
  >   `instant` - the instant to find the daylight savings for, not null, but null may be ignored if the rules have a single offset for all instants
  >
  > **Returns:**
  >   the difference between the standard and actual offset, not null
- [`ZoneOffsetTransition nextTransition(Instant instant)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#nextTransition-java.time.Instant-)

  > Gets the next transition after the specified instant.
  >
  > This returns details of the next transition after the specified instant. For example, if the instant represents a point where "Summer" daylight savings time applies, then the method will return the transition to the next "Winter" time.
  >
  > **Parameters:**
  >   `instant` - the instant to get the next transition after, not null, but null may be ignored if the rules have a single offset for all instants
  >
  > **Returns:**
  >      the next transition after the specified instant, null if this is after the last transition

To get the the `ZoneRules` you can use:

```
ZoneRules rules = ZoneId.of("Europe/Brussels").getRules();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the timezone offset from UTC in seconds in Brussels timezone of a particular timestamp, using this code snippet:

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Brussels");
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp);
OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(instant, zone);
int offsetInSeconds = dateTime.get(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS);
```

If you want to get it in hours you need to do some more work, and some countries have timezone offsets that are not whole hours.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(utcOffsetInHoursInBrussels(1498329000000L));
    System.out.println(utcOffsetInHoursInBrussels(1485282600000L));
}

public static int utcOffsetInHoursInBrussels(long timestamp) {
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Brussels");
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp);
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(instant, zone);
    int offsetInSeconds = dateTime.get(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS);
    if (offsetInSeconds % 3600 == 0) {
        return offsetInSeconds / 3600;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Offset is not a whole hour");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2
1
```

Answer (score 1):

You don’t necessarily need to go through a `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` as in the other answers.

```
    ZoneOffset offset = ZoneId.of("Europe/Brussels")
            .getRules()
            .getOffset(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1_498_329_000_000L));
```

Which you prefer is probably a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

Oles answer is the best because your simple problem to query the timezone offset for a given instant does not require to use complex types like `ZonedDateTime` at all.

**Java-8 or later (see also Oles answer):**

```
ZoneRules rules = ZoneId.of("Europe/Brussels").getRules();
ZoneOffset offsetDST = 
    rules.getOffset(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1498329000000L));
System.out.println(offsetDST); // +02:00

ZoneOffset offsetSTD =
    rules.getOffset(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1485282600000L));
System.out.println(offsetSTD); // +01:00
```

**Old API (which is surprisingly even the simplest approach):**

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Brussels");
System.out.println(tz.getOffset(1498329000000L)); // 7200000 ms
System.out.println(tz.getOffset(1485282600000L)); // 3600000 ms
```

Comment: The outdated API is the simplest for this task under the questionable assumption that you’ve got milliseconds since the epoch and you’re happy to get an offset in milliseconds back. For any work you’re doing before or after you’re likely to prefer an object representation of your stuff over bare milliseconds.

Comment: @OleV.V. Completely agree with you about the better value of object representations. I have only mentioned the old API because the OP seems to want that.